# Solving constant $k$ for invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra

For which choices of the constant $k$ is the following matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & k\\
1 & 4 & k^2
\end{pmatrix}$ invertible?

Comment: A matrix is invertible if and only if it's determinant is what value?

Comment: You better run to the FAQ section and read there the directions to post properly mathematics in this site using LaTeX: your question is very hard to understand.

Comment: if it is not invertible then it's rows and columns are not linearly independent.

Answer (score 4):

Calculate the determinant:

You'll get a quadratic in $k$.

Set the quadratic equation equal to $0$, solve for the roots (solve for the values of $k$ for which the the equation evaluates to zero). $k_1$, $k_2$.

Then, at those values, and only at those values, the matrix will NOT be invertible. (See Shu's post):

> *A square matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant does NOT equal $0$.*

For ALL other values of $k \neq k_1, k\neq k_2$, the determinant will NOT equal zero, and hence, at all those $k$, the matrix will be invertible.

---

You can confirm that the two values, $k_1$, $k_2$ which make the determinant equal to zero are indeed two problematic values. As Cutie Crait hints:  one value, say $k_1$ for which the first and third column will be linearly ***dependent***, and the other value $k_2$ for which the second and third columns will be linearly ***dependent***, and at that same value, $k_2$, row 2 and row 3 will be linearly ***dependent***. Hence at those values, $k_1, k_2$, the matrix will NOT be invertible.

The first method, however, allows you to conclude that at for ALL values $k$ NOT equal to $k_1$ and $k_2$, the matrix will be invertible, and that it is not invertible if and only if $k = k_1$ or $k = k_2$.

Comment: D-Man: we encourage users accept an answer if they find it helpful. Accepting answers that are helpful encourages others to answer future questions. (When a user doesn't accept answers on a regular basis, we are likely to think you don't like any of the answers you get and are less likely to help again.) To accept an answer (you can accept one answer per question), you simply click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer, and you get two reputation points for every answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: A matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is not $0$

So calculate its determinant.